# NAs introduced by coercion using biopsy dataset - Knn example

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the code using the Biopsy dataset from R. The idea is creating a Knn machine learning.

I appreciate your help.

I tried to run the code but I got some warnings. e.g. NAs introduced by coercion.

```
cc = c(1:100)*0
for (i in 1:100) {

L<- sample(1:nrow(biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas),round(nrow(biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas)/3))

train_sem_NA_Linhas = biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[-L,2:11]
test_sem_NA_Linhas = biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[L,2:11]

cl = factor( biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[-L, 11])
fit = knn(train_sem_NA_Linhas, test_sem_NA_Linhas, cl, k = 5)

c_matrix = table(fit[1:length(L)], factor(biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[L, 11]))
acc[i] = cat('Accurancy:', sum(diag(c_matrix))/sum(c_matrix)*100, '%')
}
mean(acc)
```

Errors below appeared:

> Error in knn(train_sem_NA_Linhas, test_sem_NA_Linhas, cl, k = 5) : 
>     NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In knn(train_sem_NA_Linhas, test_sem_NA_Linhas, cl, k = 5) :
>     NAs introduced by coercion
>   2: In knn(train_sem_NA_Linhas, test_sem_NA_Linhas, cl, k = 5) :
>     NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

The `train` and `test` data frames should not have the factor column, the last one. The factor is only supplied in `cl`. You can check this in the documentation of the `knn` function.

I removed the `cat` part because you can't take the mean of a string. But if you really want a list with messages you should try using `paste` instead.

```
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(class)

data("biopsy")

biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas <-  biopsy %>% 
  na.omit() #creatind the biopsy data "sem NA"

acc = c(1:100)*0
for (i in 1:100) {

  L<- sample(1:nrow(biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas),round(nrow(biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas)/3))
  #without the last column, the one with the factors
  train_sem_NA_Linhas = biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[-L,2:10] 
  test_sem_NA_Linhas = biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[L,2:10]

  cl = factor( biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[-L, 11])
  fit = knn(train_sem_NA_Linhas, test_sem_NA_Linhas, cl = cl, k = 5)

  c_matrix = table(fit[1:length(L)], factor(biopsy_sem_NA_nas_Linhas[L, 11]))
  acc[i] = sum(diag(c_matrix))/sum(c_matrix)*100
}
mean(acc)
```